# how to redirect to other port in playframework

Tags: redirect, playframework

can anyone tell me how to redirect to a module using another port? example: redirect from http://localhost:9000 to https://localhost:9443/login

without changing ports, i'd just use `@{Secure.login()}` in the controller but i couldn't find any way to redirect to another port..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are meant to do this, for your example, is to the .secure() method. It was added in Play 1.0.3.2.

So it would look like

```
@{Secure.login().secure()}
```

This is a special method on the router object that changes the URL from HTTP to HTTPS. The last time I checked though, it didn't change the port. I raised a bug, but not sure if it is not fixed in the 1.2 master branch yet (https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java).

The reason for this, is that play expects an HTTP server to sit infront of Play in a production environment, and handles HTTPS for you, and proxies through to Play as a simple HTTP request. The purpose of the `.secure()` is to tell the URL to switch to HTTPS, but still go through the same domain.

I don't think there are many alternatives (and none that are nice and simple).

- You could take the Play source, and altering the Router.java file, so that it also changes the port number (in the secure method).
- Or, you could write a FastTag that mimics the Router.reverse (effectively what the @ symbol does), but replace the port number with a secure one.

Comment: version of play is 1.0.3.2 (just to prevent people from searching for 1.3.2 which doesn't exist yet ;);))

Answer (score 1):

As codemwnci explained, in prod, generally Play is behind a front proxy that manages all secured channel issues and which can also be used for balancing.
The *@{Secure.login().secure()}* should work but it only changes http to https.
In addition, I would add the dumb cludge that can be used in a Controller:

```
redirect("http://www.zenexity.fr:9876");
```

;)

Comment: I would argue that this answers the question better, because I actually came here looking for this, but my problem is not related to security. The accepted answer answers the question the asker *meant* to ask, but not the one they *actually* asked.